# CAML query with Float is not returning expected results - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: caml-query

I've using SP CAML Query Helper 2013

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="Score"></FieldRef>
      <Value Type="Float">1000</Value>
    </Geq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

I'm getting all my results back. ALL of my values are between 0.0 and 1.0

Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong?

Here is what that column looks like in SP CAML Query Helper 2013 when the results come back:

```
float;#0.150000000000000
float;#0.250000000000000
float;#1.000000000000000
float;#0.450000000000000
```

I am expecting no results to come back since I'm asking for Greater than or = to 1000.

Ideally I want to put in 0.8 and get the values >= .8

Comment: Can you try with `Type="Number"` and tell me what are the results?

Answer (score 2):

You are basically doing a strange sort of cast by using `float` or it's failing because `float` is not a valid type and it's thus returning all list items.

Try

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="Score"></FieldRef>
      <Value Type="Number">1000</Value>
    </Geq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```